# Refactor case clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refactoring

I need to refactor the following rails function, Rubocop doesn't like too much complexity, I'm trying to upload a file using the 'net/sftp' library

```
  def record_answer(event, uploader, *args)
    case event
    when :open then
      Rails.logger.info "starting upload: #{args[0].local} -> #{args[0].remote} (#{args[0].size} bytes} #{uploader}"
    when :put then
      Rails.logger.info "writing #{args[2].length} bytes to #{args[0].remote} starting at #{args[1]} #{uploader}"
    when :close then
      Rails.logger.info "finished with #{args[0].remote} #{uploader}"
    when :mkdir then
      Rails.logger.info "creating directory #{args[0]} #{uploader}"
    when :finish then
      Rails.logger.info 'all done!'
    end
  end
```

I was trying to solve it with hashes but wasn't sure about the arguments

Comment: Just store the result of the case statement in a variable and pass it to the Rails.logger. Also the `then` seems superfluous.

Answer (score 1):

In Ruby everything is an expression - even case statements and if/else constructs and they return a value.

```
def record_answer(event, uploader, *args)
  Rails.logger.info case event
  when :open
    "starting upload: #{args[0].local} -> #{args[0].remote} (#{args[0].size} bytes} #{uploader}"
  when :put
    "writing #{args[2].length} bytes to #{args[0].remote} starting at #{args[1]} #{uploader}"
  when :close
    "finished with #{args[0].remote} #{uploader}"
  when :mkdir
    "creating directory #{args[0]} #{uploader}"
  when :finish
    'all done!'
  end
end
```

This lets you just call `Rails.logger.info` once with the return value of the expression.

Additionally `args[0].remote` and `args[0].size` could possibly be solved by using [keyword arguments](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/ruby-2-keyword-arguments) instead of passing a hash as a positional argument.

```
def record_answer(event, uploader, *args, remote: nil, size: nil, local: nil, **options)
  Rails.logger.info case event
  when :open
    "starting upload: #{local} -> #{remote} (#{size} bytes} #{uploader}"
  when :put
    "writing #{args[2].length} bytes to #{remote} starting at #{args[1]} #{uploader}"
  when :close
    "finished with #{remote} #{uploader}"
  when :mkdir
    "creating directory #{args[0]} #{uploader}"
  when :finish
    'all done!'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the horrible question I posted, the thing was Rubocop was asking to refactor because has a too much complexity, I found the solution

I create a handler class

```
class SFTPEventHandler
  def on_open(uploader, file)
    Rails.logger.info "starting upload: #{file.local} -> #{file.remote} (#{file.size} bytes) #{uploader}"
  end

  def on_put(uploader, file, offset, data)
    Rails.logger.info "writing #{data.length} bytes to #{file.remote} starting at #{offset} #{uploader}"
  end

  def on_close(uploader, file)
    Rails.logger.info "finished with #{file.remote} #{uploader}"
  end

  def on_mkdir(uploader, path)
    Rails.logger.info "creating directory #{path} #{uploader}"
  end

  def on_finish(uploader)
   Rails.logger.info "all done! #{uploader}"
  end
end
```

Then I called it in the upload function as a parameter supported by 'net/sftp'

```
sftp.upload!('x.txt', 'x.txt', progress: SFTPEventHandler.new)
```